# How to give a group in AWS IAM Identity Center to a Policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-security-group, aws-policies

I have a policy called Lightsail Developers:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lightsail:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

In "IAM Identity Center" I created a user, and put him in the group "LightsailDevelopers".
Not, how do I add that group to the above policy?  Do I add a SID statement?  Is it done by the picking and choosing in the console, or by editing the JSON of the policy?

Comment: **Warning:** AWS IAM Identity Center is used for Single-Sign On. It is different to "IAM". Are you sure that you want to use Identity Center rather than IAM? (AWS' choice of naming here is terrible and prone to mistakes.)

Comment: It looked like something new that I thought I would try.  I forgot how to give console logon to an IAM (which is what I ended up doing), but the idea of inviting an email to me made sense.